# Pass variable from one WordPress hook to another

Tags: arrays, wordpress, action, hook

I have functions for two WordPress hooks: `admin_menu` and `save_post`

First I declare an associative array, which is called as global in both functions.

In the `admin_menu` function, I'm adding an additional key & value to the end of the array and I want the updated array to be available to the `save_post` function.

```
$my_array = array(  

"key1" => "value1", 
"key2" => "value2"

);

my_admin_function() {

global $my_array;
$my_array["key3"] => "value3";

}

my_save_function() {

global $my_array;

}

add_action('admin_menu', 'my_admin_function');

add_action('save_post', 'my_save_function');
```

In the above example, `$my_array` in `my_save_function` still only has 2 key/value pairs.

I can't figure out how to get my third key into `my_save_function` so it will get saved!

(Note: In my full code I'm using `my_admin_function` to add a meta box which cycles through an array of form fields, and then adds another field to the array. I'm then trying to save all of the fields in `my_save_function'.)

Comment: Please explain why do you want to do this ?

Comment: I still don't understand what you are trying to achieve, do you simply  want to add custom fields to your post ??

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your first comment. The meta box code I use cycles through an array of fields that gets set up at the start, both to display the fields in the meta box, and then again to save them. I am adding a feature so the user can add additional copies of certain fields where the number needed is variable. I need to be able to add the new fields to the array so they can be saved, as well as a hidden field that gives me the total of additional fields.

Comment: So you don't need `$my_array` in `my_save_function`, juste `$_POST`

Comment: Well, when you put it THAT way... :)   
`my_save_function` verifies the nonce for each field this way: `if ( !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST[$my_array['name'].'_noncename'], plugin_basename(__FILE__) )) { return $post_id; }`, and then gets the $_POST values this way: `$data = $_POST[$my_array['name']];`. I don't understand how to code the nonce verification without using the array.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you cannot do this because `save_post` action occurs **before** `admin_menu` action.

You should use another hook, e.g. `init`.

Comment: I tried changing my admin_menu function to run on admin_init, but there was no change. save_post is still not getting the additional key/value pair.

Comment: I didn't say `admin_init`, just `init`

Comment: I was concerned that `init` would fire on every page, and not just the admin.

But when I attach `my_admin_function` to `init`, it doesn't seem to work. 

In my full code I'm adding a meta box which cycles through an array of form fields. I'm then adding another field to the array in `my_admin_function` and trying to save all of the fields in `my_save_function'. (I'll add that note to the main question.)

When I try `init` as the hook, my meta box does not appear at all.

Comment: Of course it will not work with your existing `my_admin_function` code, but it will fire before any other hook. Whatever, I think your code's logic is not good.

Comment: Thank you VERY much for your help, @soju -- yes, my code's logic was faulty (no surprise there). In the end I felt it was more secure to stick with the array rather than $_POST to make sure only the expected fields get saved, but I found a way to add the extra key to the array within `my_save_function` to avoid the problem in the first place. Thanks again!